# Error message when porting Shopware to Docker with Dockware: 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Permission denied'

Tags: docker, docker-compose, shopware

I am trying to port a Shopware instance that was previously running on a server to a Docker container using Dockware. I have used dockware/essentials:latest and configured the environment variables in the .env file in the container accordingly (see code snippet below).

However, when calling localhost in the browser I get the error message "Could not connect to database. Message from SQL Server: An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Permission denied".

What can I do to solve this problem?

#### .env file

```
# This file is a "template" of which env vars need to be defined for your application
# Copy this file to .env file for development, create environment variables when deploying to production
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/configuration.html#infrastructure-related-configuration

###> symfony/framework-bundle ###
APP_ENV=dev
APP_SECRET=<Secret>
APP_URL=localhost
TRUSTED_PROXIES=localhost,127.0.0.1
TRUSTED_HOSTS=localhost,127.0.0.1
###< symfony/framework-bundle ###

###> symfony/swiftmailer-bundle ###
# For Gmail as a transport, use: "gmail://username:password@localhost"
# For a generic SMTP server, use: "smtp://localhost:25?encryption=&auth_mode="
# Delivery is disabled by default via "null://localhost"
MAILER_URL=null://localhost
###< symfony/swiftmailer-bundle ###

DATABASE_URL=mysql://<username>:<password>@localhost:3306/<db_name>

COMPOSER_HOME=/var/www/html/var/cache/composer

INSTANCE_ID=<id>

BLUE_GREEN_DEPLOYMENT=1

SHOPWARE_HTTP_CACHE_ENABLED=1
SHOPWARE_HTTP_DEFAULT_TTL=7200
SHOPWARE_ES_HOSTS=""
SHOPWARE_ES_ENABLED="1"
SHOPWARE_ES_INDEXING_ENABLED="0"
SHOPWARE_ES_INDEX_PREFIX="sw"

SHOPWARE_CDN_STRATEGY_DEFAULT="id"
```

#### docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: "3"

services:

    shopware:
      # use either tag "latest" or any other version like "6.5.3.0", ...
      image: dockware/essentials:latest
      container_name: shopware
      ports:
         - "80:80"
         - "3306:3306"
         - "22:22"
         - "8888:8888"
         - "9999:9999"
      volumes:
         - "db_volume:/var/lib/mysql"
         - "shop_volume:/var/www/html"
      networks:
         - web
      environment:
         # default = 0, recommended to be OFF for frontend devs
         - XDEBUG_ENABLED=1
         # default = latest PHP, optional = specific version
         - PHP_VERSION=8.1
         

volumes:
  db_volume:
    driver: local
  shop_volume:
    driver: local

networks:
  web:
    external: false
```

I attempted to port an existing Shopware instance from a traditional server setup to a Docker container using Dockware. To do this, I utilized the dockware/essentials:latest image and configured the necessary environment variables in the .env file within the container. Specifically, I ensured that the database connection details (host, port, database name, username, and password) were correctly set to match those of the MySQL service running in another Docker container.

I expected that after configuring the environment variables and running the containers, I would be able to access the Shopware instance by navigating to localhost in my browser without encountering any database connection issues. However, upon doing so, I received the error message. This was unexpected and indicates a problem with the database connection within the Docker setup.

Comment: I have removed the <sql> tag since this isn't about the SQL _language_. Instead add a tag for the dbms you're using.